# VMware: cannot ping host machine

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, vlan

I am running VMware workstation 7 - hosting a linux machine.  From this virtual linux machine i can ping all other machines on my network except the machine thats hosting it.

All other machines on the network cannot ping the host machine either.

All other machine on the network cannot ping the virtual machine as well.

VMWARE setting?

Network setting on host machine?

------ i added some facts --------

Machine A - Other windows PC

Machine B - VM Host Machine

Machine C - VM Guest Machine

- A cannot ping B or C
- B cannot ping A or C
- C can ping A
- C cannot ping B
- A,B,and C have access to the internet and have seperate IP addresses.

Yes i have tried ip addresses instead of machine names.

Virtual Machine Network adapter is set to "Bridged"... but not "Replicate physical network connection state".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running VMware Workstation on a Windows box that has its firewall set to drop ICMP echo packets.  Fixing that depends on what version of windows you are running.

Comment: I am running XP SP3

Comment: echo requests are enabled.

Comment: On which interface(s)? You'll need to make sure they aren't blocked on the VMware network adapter interface as well. I just tried it on a PC of mine with Windows 7 as a host and XP SP3 as the guest - provided the ICMP echo request was correctly set on the correct interface it works.

Comment: It was enabled on all three but i allowed some more icmp stuff and everything seems to be working great.

Thanks!